# Spotify won't launch anymore (Snap error: cannot update snap namespace)

Tags: snap

```
$ snap refresh
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "spotify" (63) security profiles (cannot update mount namespace of snap "spotify": cannot update preserved namespace of snap "spotify": cannot update snap namespace: remove /usr/bin/gjs: read-only file system)
$ spotify
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface.
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you rebooted since seeing the message? It's suboptimal, but this will often resolve the issue ...

Comment: I initially didn't want to reboot and lose my session but have since done so and it indeed solved the issue for now

Comment: Reboot and then `sudo snap refresh` again "*solved*" this for me, but this seems like a work-around rather than a solution (`spotify 1.2.8.923.g4f94bf0d`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug right now. A solution can be found here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/spotify-snap-update-failed-version-1-2-8-923-g4f94bf0d/34586

Essentially:

```
snap remove spotify # uninstall, do take note of the ID of the snapshot that will be generated
snap install spotify # reinstall
snap restore <the-snapshot-id> spotify # restore user data from the snapshot
```

While there *probably* is a better way to fix the root cause, this way is fast and works.